# Codeigniter: I want to use URL routing for my site

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I am using codeigniter for my project and I have two modules "Admin" and "User". And I have the following structure for controllers->User->User_controllers and I have routed the url like:

```
$route['register'] = "user/user_controller/register";
```

But it is giving me 404 Error. Any clues what I am doing wrong. The index page is working well which I have routed as:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "user/user_controller";
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add basic structure of user controller, thanks. (eg, class and methods)

Comment: Check if using /index.php/register still 404.

Comment: Yes it works with index.php but how can I remove the index.php and still make this URL work. Also post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: You have to use modify your .htaccess file to remove index.php. See this http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/155801/

Comment: Yes this works well. Please post this as an answer so that i can accept it